# Run-time Error, variable matches no exports, missing module reference EXCEL VBA

Tags: excel, vba

the following code sets cell B21 to a variable and then reference that variable to download data from the website.

**The error I get:**
Code with Variable (broken):
Error: Run-time error '1004':
[Expression.Error] The import TICKER matches no exports. Did you miss a module reference?

```vb
Sub DownloadDataV5()
'
' DownloadDataV5 Macro

    Range("B21").Select
    Selection.Copy
' WEBLINK CODE that takes data from cell that combines TICKER & START DATE & ENDING DATE
    Dim WEBLINK As String
    WEBLINK = Sheets("Download").Cells(21, "B").Value
' comment
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table 0", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents((TICKER)))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Data0 = Source{0}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data0,{{""Buy/Sell"", type text}, {""Transaction Date"", type date}, {""Acceptance DateTime"", type" & _
        " datetime}, {""Issuer Name"", type text}, {""Issuer Trading Symbol"", type text}, {""Reporting Owner Name"", type text}, {""Reporting Owner Relationship"", type text}, {""Transaction Shares"", Int64.Type}, {""Price per Share"", Currency.Type}, {""Total Value"", Currency.Type}, {""Shares Owned Following Transaction"", Int64.Type}, {""Form"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""" & _
        "Changed Type"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "MySheet"
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""Table 0"";Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Table 0]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_0"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Sheets("Download").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries("Table 0").Delete
End Sub
```

The following code WORKS, but it's useless because it doesn't reference a variable.

```vb
Sub DownloadDataV5()
'
' DownloadDataV5 Macro

    Range("B21").Select
    Selection.Copy
' comment
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table 0", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents((""http://insidertrading.org/index.php?sort_by=acceptance_datetime&asc=&symbol=GOOG&date_from=2016-08-03&date_to=2020-12-16&submit=+GO+&page=1"")))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Data0 = Source{0}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data0,{{""Buy/Sell"", type text}, {""Transaction Date"", type date}, {""Acceptance DateTime"", type" & _
        " datetime}, {""Issuer Name"", type text}, {""Issuer Trading Symbol"", type text}, {""Reporting Owner Name"", type text}, {""Reporting Owner Relationship"", type text}, {""Transaction Shares"", Int64.Type}, {""Price per Share"", Currency.Type}, {""Total Value"", Currency.Type}, {""Shares Owned Following Transaction"", Int64.Type}, {""Form"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""" & _
        "Changed Type"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "MySheet"
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""Table 0"";Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Table 0]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_0"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Sheets("Download").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries("Table 0").Delete
End Sub
```

Just need a super quick fix to get this working. Would appreciate all the help I can get!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the reference to the Weblink variable inside the query's formula

```
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table 0", Formula:= _
    "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents((" & Chr(34) & WEBLINK & Chr(34) & ")))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Data0 = Source{0}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data0,{{""Buy/Sell"", type text}, {""Transaction Date"", type date}, {""Acceptance DateTime"", type" & _
    " datetime}, {""Issuer Name"", type text}, {""Issuer Trading Symbol"", type text}, {""Reporting Owner Name"", type text}, {""Reporting Owner Relationship"", type text}, {""Transaction Shares"", Int64.Type}, {""Price per Share"", Currency.Type}, {""Total Value"", Currency.Type}, {""Shares Owned Following Transaction"", Int64.Type}, {""Form"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""" & _
    "Changed Type"""
```

See how I concatenated the variable and added the double quotes here:

```
" & Chr(34) & WEBLINK & Chr(34) & "
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: Thanks so much Ricardo!